# Testing In-App purchases on iOS 5 device

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

1. I am able to query products from the `SKProductsRequest`
2. I can add a new payment with the `SKPaymentQueue` object
3. I get the OS dialog confirming the purchase
4. When I touch 'OK' the device **prompts me to log in with my real Apple ID** instead of the test account.

Before testing I created an itunes connect test user.  Then signed out my real apple id on the device.  The app is being transfered when connect to Xcode in debug mode.

Why is it not allowing me to enter my itunes connect test account?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting and recreating the in-app purchase on itunes connect solved the problem.

Comment: +1 however, you then have to change the product identifier to something new. But it worked in my case as well.